# Get large event pictures from Facebook

Tags: json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using a simple query to grab event photos, but it seems the maximum I can retrieve is a 200px by 200px photo. I've tried the following for bigger photos:

```
var fb_image = "http://graph.facebook.com/"+eventnum+"/picture?width=9999&height=9999";
```

No matter what, the picture returns as a 200x200 photo. Any ideas? Or, better yet, is there a way to grab the cover photo using the same method?

Answer (score 0):

Use FQL via Graph API:

https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT pic,pic_big,pic_small FROM event WHERE eid= eventnum

You need an active Accesstoken

Comment: I was trying to avoid this, people have claimed they are able to achieve what I'm trying to do just through the json queries.

Comment: JSON isn’t even involved in the code you’ve shown in your question …